# Encoding both numbers and text in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I'd like to process symbolic equation in a neural network using keras. For a simple example, assume the input is two lines (i.e. 2x + 4y + 2 = 0, -x +7y -4 = 0) and the output is 0 if the lines intersect and 1 if they are parallel.
In order to do so, the equations needed to be encoded somehow. Using it just as a text does not work, and the problem, in my opinion, is that the encoding does not keep the order between the numbers.
Is there a way to encode text and numbers differently such that the order between numbers is kept?

Comment: Do you have always two variables?

Comment: no. It can change